# Java - looping in 1 class & adding element to array in another

Tags: java

I have two classes, one running the Main method has the following `for` loop:

```
for (int b = startRecipe; b <= endRecipe; b++)
        {
            Rec = fileScan.nextLine() + "\n";
        }
        System.out.println(theRecipe.addRecipeStep(Rec));
```

In my other class, I have the following loop:

```
 public String[] addRecipeStep(String Rec ){

        for (int a = 0; a < maxNumOfSteps; a++)
            recipeSteps[a] = Rec;

        return recipeSteps;

    }
```

`int maxNumOfSteps` can be accessed across the two classes. My first question is, I would like to loop over the first loop, and for every `Rec` value, I would like to add it to my `recipeSteps` array in the second loop. For right now, the second loop only adds the last value that `Rec` takes, understandably (and the array contains the same thing in all the indices). If I do `Rec +=` and add every `Rec` values to 1 index of the array (everything shows up), then it is against the program requirements. Ideally, I should have as many indices in the 2nd array as there are numbers of `Rec` values.

Problem # 2 is, when I call the `addRecipeStep(param)` from the `main` class, it prints out "trash." I have attempted to use `toString()` but there has been no successes yet. All advices are welcomed.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since addRecpieStep is in one class, and your first loop is in another, you will need a refrence to the class containing addRecepieStep. Then simply call that method each time in your loop with the value of rec.

In addRecpieStep you need to change a bit. Earlier you overwrote all elements with the value of rec, but you simply want to add it to the end of the list. So addRecpieStep you want to loop until you find a null value, and add the element to that position:

```
    for (int b = startRecipe; b <= endRecipe; b++)
    {
        rec = fileScan.nextLine() + "\n";
        refrenceToYourClassContainingAddRecipeStep.addRecipeStep(rec); //add this line
    }


 public String[] addRecipeStep(String rec ){

          for (int a = 0; a < maxNumOfSteps; a++){
              if(receipeStep[a]==null  // loop until you reached a empty spot in your string arrray
                 recipeSteps[a] = rec;  // add rec to your empty spot
                 break;            
          }

        return recipeSteps;

    }
```

To explain, when you do this (as you did in your example):

```
public String[] addRecipeStep(String Rec ){

        for (int a = 0; a < maxNumOfSteps; a++)
            recipeSteps[a] = Rec;

        return recipeSteps;
    }
```

you overwrite the whole array with the value of rec since it will loop thru the array, and add rec to each position which is not what you want

As for the printing of the array I will leave it up to you to complete. But, you will need to loop thru the array, and call println on each element. So, write a method that takes an array as parameter, loops thru the array and calls println every loop. Good luck

Comment: Hi Jim, I created an object for the class containing addRecipeSteps, so would object.addRecipeSteps(Rec) be sufficient? I've added the `while` but I am getting `null`'s.  Please advise.

Comment: if the refrence to that object is named object, then object.addRecipeSteps(rec) would work. As for your null value, ive edited my post a bit. Try it out with the change

Comment: Yes, saw it.  But now, it only prints out the first `Rec` value.

Comment: Since I created an obj for that class, could I somehow jump back to main by referencing something?

Comment: Well, i have no idea how you implemented your print method. You need to make sure that you loop thru the array and call println each iteration of the loop. If that is working it might be the case that your recepieStep array is out of scope, and returns to null before you print it

Comment: once the addRecepieStep method is done running you will "return" to your main class automaticly. Im sure you know that, that is very basic stuff. If not i advise you to read a bit on how a java program executes